# Copy an older version of an existing file into a seperate file which preserves history

Tags: git

We have multiple documentation files which are updated per release inside our repo. We now decide we want to keep previous versions of the documentation inside the `HEAD` commit of our repo.

We decide we'd like all versions past-and-present to live inside sub-folders of the original `doc/` folder. Great, except if we just move the current in-dev docs to say `indev/` and copy-paste docs from different places in time, we're going to lose the commit history of specific files, and generally create a huge ugly diff. My question is: is there a way to preserve such history for older versions of these (currently existant) files.

A minimal reproducer of sorts:

1. Document for the first release in just the `doc/` folder.

```bash
$ git init
$ mkdir doc
$ touch doc/index.html
$ echo "<h1>Hello world!</h1>" >> doc/index.html
$ git add doc/index.html
$ git commit -m "init"
$ echo "<p>This package allows you to...</p>" >> doc/index.html
$ git commit -a -m "basic docs"
$ git tag 1.0
```

So the history looks like:

```bash
$ git blame doc/index.html
commit 0: doc/index.html "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
commit 1: doc/index.html "<p>This package allows you to...</p>"
```

2. Start documenting for the second release...

```bash
$ echo "<p>New feature: ...</p>" >> doc/index.html
$ git commit -a -m "document new feature"
$ git blame doc/index.html
commit 0: doc/index.html "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
commit 1: doc/index.html "<p>This package allows you to...</p>"
commit 2: doc/index.html "<p>New feature: ...</p>"
```

3. Realise you want to keep older doc versions in the repo's `HEAD`

```bash
$ mkdir doc/1.0 doc/2.0
$ git mv doc/index.html doc/2.0/index.html
$ git blame doc/2.0/index.html
commit 0: doc/2.0/index.html "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
commit 1: doc/2.0/index.html "<p>This package allows you to...</p>"
commit 2: doc/2.0/index.html "<p>New feature: ...</p>"
```

4. ???
5. Profit!

```bash
$ tree
.
└── doc
    ├── 1.0
    │   └── index.html
    └── 2.0
        └── index.html
$ git blame doc/1.0/index.html
commit 0: doc/1.0/index.html "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
commit 1: doc/1.0/index.html "<p>This package allows you to...</p>"
```

Comment: Git can (generally) track history between file renames and moves. Why do you feel the need to copy-paste stuff?

Comment: See reproducer, I don't just want to move files and have their history kept, but "split" files so they exist in multiple places in the repo, with each file having history pre-split preserved.

Comment: That's not a thing.  Git doesn't know what you intend when you split files; all it knows is that you've created a new file and haven't just moved another file somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Create a branch at the time you want to create the copy. In that branch, *move* the file to its new location. Then merge that branch back to head, making sure the file doesn't get deleted in head (restore it if necessary). Details: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190919-00/?p=102904

Comment: @RaymondChen I would definitely upvote it if you write the full recipe as an answer, linking the document. Specially, the merge step so the OP can get the file back.

Comment: `git checkout -b temp past-commit; git mv file file-archive; git commit -m "Archive staging"; git checkout main; git merge --no-commit --no-ff temp; git checkout HEAD -- file; git checkout temp -- file-archive; git commit -m "Archive file@yyyy/mm/dd as file-archive"`

Comment: Thanks so much @RaymondChen! Wrote an answer using your clever methodology.

Comment: Note that Git really does not have *file* history: it has *commits* and the commits *are* the history. Everything beyond that is synthetic: `git log` and `git blame` try to detect file renames and file copies and hence carry information across those commit boundaries. The degree to which this succeeds or fails depends on how clever Git is at finding renames/copies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by some (mis)use of merging diverged branches.
Thanks to Raymond Chen for their comments and [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190919-00/?p=102904) on the matter!

Following the reproducer in my original question, at step 4 we could first commit moving the current docs to a sub-folder.

```bash
$ git commit -m "move current docs to 2.0 sub-folder"
$ tree
.
└── doc
    └── 2.0
        └── index.html
```

Then we deal with having a blameable `doc/1.0/index.html`. We can create a branch from the commit before we start updating the docs for `2.0`, which has the then-`1.0` docs already moved to `doc/1.0`.

```bash
$ git checkout -b temp <hash>
$ git mv doc/index.html doc/1.0/index.html
$ git commit -m "move older docs to 1.0 sub-folder"
```

We can go back to our main branch and merge this temporary branch.

```bash
$ git checkout main
$ git merge --no-commit --no-ff temp
CONFLICT (rename/rename): doc/index.html renamed to doc/2.0/index.html in HEAD and to doc/1.0/index.html in temp.
$ git status
On branch main
You have unmerged paths.
Unmerged paths:
    added by them:   doc/1.0/index.html
    added by us:     doc/2.0/index.html
    both deleted:    doc/index.html
```

We resolve the conflicts by checking out the files from the respective branches.

```bash
$ git checkout temp -- doc/1.0/index.html
$ git checkout HEAD -- doc/2.0/index.html
$ git rm doc/index.html
$ git status
On branch main
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
Changes to be committed:
    new file:   doc/1.0/index.html
$ git commit -m "merge older version of docs"
```

And we're done!

```bash
$ tree
.
└── doc
    ├── 1.0
    │   └── index.html
    └── 2.0
        └── index.html
$ git blame doc/1.0/index.html
commit 0: doc/1.0/index.html "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
commit 1: doc/1.0/index.html "<p>This package allows you to...</p>"
```

Note we don't just `git checkout temp -- doc/1.0/index.html` without merging first, as we would lose the history.